# skinning of Tab & Fade out effect while switching to next tab

Tags: javafx-2

1. want to change the skin of tab, where i need the Graident mix to be used, is it possible ?
2. how to use Animations( Fading of Old Panel to New Panel) while switching to next tab.
   any help pls?

Answer (score 1):

You can change skin of your tab with simple css. For example

```
   tabName.setStyle("-fx-background-color:  linear-gradient(#2EB8B8 , #2EB8B8 )");
```

For implementing fade in/fade out animaiton check this tutorial:

```
http://java-buddy.blogspot.com/2012/02/implement-fade-infade-out-animation.html
```